# How can we export data in JSP to excel sheet?

Tags: excel, jsp

I am exporting data to an Excel sheet in JSP.

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell"%>
<% 
  String inj1=request.getParameter("inj"); 
  String ob=request.getParameter("ob"); 
  HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
  HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet"); 
  HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)0);
  rowhead.createCell((short)0).setCellValue("Injections");
  rowhead.createCell((short)1).setCellValue("OB");
  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)1);
  row.createCell((short)0).setCellValue(inj1);
  row.createCell((short)1).setCellValue(ob);
  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:\\Injection_Details.xls");
  wb.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  out.println("Data is saved in excel file.");
%>
```

I am getting errors as

> HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type

or

> Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet resolves to a package.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Don't put code like this in your JSP. It belongs in plain Java Code. If you aren't using it already pick up a proper Java Framework, for example Spring MVC. If you already use one, learn to use it properly.

Answer (score 1):

> HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type

That's just a compilation error. The mentioned class is missing in the classpath. In this particular case, you need to ensure that you've dropped the necessary JAR file(s) of [Apache POI HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder (which is part of the webapp's classpath).

This problem has nothing to do with JSPs. You would have exactly the same problem in a normal Java class where all that Java code *actually* belongs.

Comment: But I tried this code and it ran successfully but the problem is that if I access database values and then try as given in this code then it wont work. Why I unable to understand. So still do you think that its a problem with the missing jar file.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Excel export without any additional libs:

1. Write your `ResultSet` out as comma-delimited data in the JSP
2. Set the ContentType on the response to Excel.

JSP Code; note the absence of line breaks in the JSP as those will mess up the CSV to Excel translation:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %><% response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename=export.csv"); %>
message_name,subject,sent_count,open_count,original_href,link_uuid,link_click_count
<c:forEach var="item" items="${myResultSet}">"<c:out value="${item.field1}" />","<c:out value="${item.field2}" />","<c:out value="${item.field3}" />"
```